# How to copy data without also copying the row/column width

Tags: excel, vba

I am using VBA to copy and paste a variable number of rows from one sheet to another when they meet a criteria.

This is working. However, when the data is pasted into the target sheet the column and row width change to be the same as the source sheet.

How can I stop this from happening? So that just the data is pasted, without the cell formatting.

If anyone knows it would be much appreciated.

Heres the code I'm using.

```
Sub copyOverdue()

Dim cell As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Action Register")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

j = 36     ' Paste to this number row
For Each cell In Source.Range("A7:A243")
    If c = "Overdue" Then
       Source.Range("A" & c.row & "," & "G" & c.row).Copy Target.Range("AD" & j)
       Source.Range("C" & c.row & "," & "F" & c.row & "," & "H" & c.row & "," & "K" & c.row).Copy Target.Range("AF" & j)
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next cell
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pastespecial values only

```
For Each cell In Source.Range("A7:A243")
    If cell.value = "Overdue" Then
       cell.Resize(, 7).Copy
       Target.Range("AD" & j).PasteSpecial xlValues
       Source.Range("C" & cell.Row & "," & "F" & cell.Row & "," & "H" & cell.Row & "," & "K" & cell.Row).Copy
       Target.Range("AF" & j).PasteSpecial xlValues
       j = j + 1
    End If
Next cell
```

You can also avoid the clipboard altogether and transfer the values directly, which is more efficient but it can get a bit mess you are dealing with large ranges.

```
Target.Range("AD" & j).Resize(,7).Value=cell.Resize(, 7).value
```

Comment: Your code seems to be almost working but the line starting with source.range is causing a Run-Time error 424, Object Required.

Comment: I've just noticed your loop variable is `cell` but the code refers to `c` which is undefined so your original code can't have worked. I've amended the code above.

Comment: Yeah I noticed that too only in your code though. I'm not sure how my original code worked either with it as just c. But your code is working but it just also throws the error.